# How to get rid of derby.log, metastore_db from Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark, derby

When running `spark-shell` it creates a file `derby.log` and a folder `metastore_db`. How do I configure spark to put these somewhere else?

For derby log I've tried [Getting rid of derby.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004327/getting-rid-of-derby-log) like so `spark-shell --driver-memory 10g --conf "-spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=Dderby.stream.info.file=/dev/null"` with a couple of different properties but spark ignores them.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these or specify a default directory for them?

Comment: You typed `derby.stream.info.file` in your question's text. The question you linked to, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004327/getting-rid-of-derby-log says to configure `derby.stream.error.file`. Which one did you actually try?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The use of the `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0, 
[see the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables).

As hinted by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40541384/7414397), the real culprit for both the `metastore_db` directory and the `derby.log` file being created in every working subdirectory is the `derby.system.home` property defaulting to `.`.

Thus, a default location for both can be specified by adding the following line to `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dderby.system.home=/tmp/derby
```

where `/tmp/derby` can be replaced by the directory of your choice.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Using spark 2.2 :(

Comment: I tested on a new installation of Spark 2.2.1 and it's working for me. maybe it has to do with permissions?

Comment: I tried with `spark.config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dderby.system.home=D:\\tmp\\derby")` using Spark 2.2.0 and it didn't work.

Comment: it seems that you are trying to change the configuration _after_ launching the Spark context. But by then it's too late for this setting... You need to change the Spark default configuration in the `spark-defaults.conf` file as explained above...

Answer (score 17):

For spark-shell, to avoid having the `metastore_db` directory and avoid doing it in the code (since the context/session is already created and you won't  stop them and recreate them with the new configuration each time), you have to set its location in `hive-site.xml`  file and copy this file into spark conf directory.
A sample `hive-site.xml` file to make the location of `metastore_db` in `/tmp`  (refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35990752/1314742)):

```
<configuration>
   <property>
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
     <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/tmp/metastore_db;create=true</value>
     <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
     <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
     <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
      <value>/tmp/</value>
      <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

After that you could start your `spark-shell` as the following to get rid of  `derby.log` as well

```
$ spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dderby.stream.error.file=/tmp"
```

Comment: How to disable derby entirely in standalone. A lot of the old methods (postgres setup + db creation + hive-site.xml appear to be no longer working on spark 2.2)

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `derby.system.home` to some other directory as a system property before firing up the spark shell. Derby will create new databases there. The default value for this property is `.`

Reference: https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/properties.html

Answer (score 3):

For me setting the Spark property didn't work, neither on the driver nor the executor. So searching for this issue, I ended up setting the property for my system instead with:

```scala
System.setProperty("derby.system.home", "D:\\tmp\\derby")

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("UT session")
    .master("local[*]")
    .enableHiveSupport
    .getOrCreate

[...]
```

And that finally got me rid of those annoying items.

Answer (score 2):

Use `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property. [From docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables):

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

For derby log: [Getting rid of derby.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1004327/6022341) could be the answer. In general create `derby.properties` file in **your working directory** with following content:

```
derby.stream.error.file=/path/to/desired/log/file
```

Comment: You can use `derby.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are using Jupyter/Jupyterhub/Jupyterlab or just setting this conf parameter inside python, use the following will work:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = (SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions','-Dderby.system.home=/tmp/derby')
   )

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below configuration for a pyspark project, i was able to setup sparkwarehouse db and derby db in sample path, so was able to avoid them setup in current directory.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from os.path import abspath
location = abspath("C:\self\demo_dbx\data\spark-warehouse") #Path where you want to setup sparkwarehouse 
local_spark = SparkSession.builder \
                .master("local[*]") \
                .appName('Spark_Dbx_Session') \
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", location)\
                .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", 
                     f"Dderby.system.home='{location}'")\
                .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i am using pyspark 3.5 / ubuntu 20.04LTS
here the conf and it works fine for me  :

```
location = "/home/amine/Desktop/myderby"

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/home/amine/Desktop/spark-warehouse") \
        .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions",
                f"-Dderby.system.home='{location}'") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
```

and create a file derby.properties in your working directory and put :
derby.stream.error.file=**/home/amine/Desktop/myderby**/derby.log

Note That the root path should be the same between location and derby.stream.error.file