# Prebuilt Spark 2.1.0 creates metastore_db folder and derby.log when launching spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I just upgraded from Spark 2.0.2 to Spark 2.1.0 (by downloading the prebuilt version for Hadoop 2.7&later). No Hive is installed.

Upon launch of the spark-shell, the `metastore_db/` folder and `derby.log` file are created at the launch location, together with a bunch of warning logs (which were not printed in the previous version).

Closer inspection of the debug logs shows that Spark 2.1.0 tries to initialise a `HiveMetastoreConnection`:

`17/01/13 09:14:44 INFO HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.`

Similar debug logs for Spark 2.0.2 do not show any initialisation of `HiveMetastoreConnection`.

Is this intended behaviour? Could it be related to the fact that `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` is now a static configuration shared among sessions? How do I avoid this, since I have no Hive installed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Spark 2.1.0 [documentation pages](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html):

> When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically
>   creates metastore_db in the current directory and creates a directory
>   configured by spark.sql.warehouse.dir, which defaults to the directory
>   spark-warehouse in the current directory that the Spark application is
>   started. Note that the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property in
>   hive-site.xml is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use
>   spark.sql.warehouse.dir to specify the default location of database in
>   warehouse.

Since you do not have Hive installed, you will not have a hive-site.xml config file, and this must be defaulting to the current directory.

If you are not planning to use `HiveContext` in Spark, you could reinstall Spark 2.1.0 from source, rebuilding it with Maven and making sure you omit `-Phive -Phive-thriftserver` flags which enable Hive support.

Comment: Thanks, that must indeed be the case. I hoped I could avoid rebuilding from source just to avoid that these folders are created but I see no other way.

Answer (score 5):

For future googlers: the actual underlying reason for the creation of `metastore_db` and `derby.log` in every working directory is the default value of `derby.system.home`.

This can be changed in `spark-defaults.conf`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44048667/7414397).

Comment: See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4758 for a way to avoid creating the `metastore_db` by requesting an embedded, volatile, **in-memory** Derby database.

Comment: See also https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html for how to set also the `hive.exec.scratchdir` property.

Answer (score 0):

This happen also with Spark 1.6. You can change the path by adding in Spark submit extra options:

```
-Dderby.system.home=/tmp/derby
```

(or by derby.properties, there are several ways to change it).